# REST: Why expose POST and PUT endpoint of API when both can be done with just any one of these endpoints?

Tags: rest, api-design

We are creating an ecommerce website where several sellers would push their products through an API exposed. Each seller has its own unique identifier for each product (product_id + seller_id) that they send with each request. Hence, they do not rely on "product id" generated by our system to send PUT request after POST.

For each of our client we have to tell to send POST only for already not created stocks, PUT only for already created stocks. Clients need to keep log of all already created stocks and based on that decide which API to hit. On API side too, we send validation error if we get POST for already existing stock OR PUT for non-existing stock.

I want to understand why do we have to keep this complexity on client and server when things could have been simplified if we choose just one of these request that would CREATE/UPDATE according to the situation.

For example if choose only POST. We will create product if request comes and it does not exist OR update it if it is already present.

Why REST suggests to keep POST/PUT separately?

Comment: I think you should be able to implement only put in your case. Also, this seems to be related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a semantic difference in PUT and POST. First consider the URI you execute the requests against:

```
POST /products
```

This adds a new product. The resulting product ID is not yet known and will be generated when it is added to the database. Posting the same product twice will result in two exactly same entries in the catalog. This may be intentional behavior in a REST API. (Maybe not in your case though.)

```
PUT /products/235647
```

This updates an existing product. The id is known to the client and this ensures that only that resource is updated. A POST against the URI does not make little sense.

When you want to add further data to the element, you would use a more specific URI:

```
POST /products/235647/reviews
```

And then update that data:

```
PUT /products/235647/reviews/2
```

Separating the `Create` and `Update` verbs ensures that duplicates are created intentionally and not by mistake. Also the URIs are significantly different and thus you need different handlers anyway.

Comment: The situation is bit different in our case. The sellers do not use product id generated in our system to send PUT request. They send (unique_seller_id + unique_product_id). As each seller mantains its own unique product ids and seller id. I have editted the question. Please check.

Comment: So? It does not matter that the ID is generated by the client or your code. The basic logic is the same. `POST /product/:id` is just asking for trouble. The API ensures that the INTENT of the request is sane.

Comment: Yes. I agree that this ensures that the request is sane but in our case it comes with all the cost of checking PUT only after POST etc. Is there any other reason you can think of creating both POST and PUT?